# The sums over RVs between two return times are independent for a Markov chain

Tags: probability, markov-chains

Let $X_0,X_1,...,X_n,...$ be an **irreducible** Markov chain with **finite state space**. Define $τ_{x,0}^+=0$, and $τ_{x,k}^+=\min\{t:t>τ_{x,k-1}^+,X_t=x\}$. In plain words, $τ_{x,k}^+$ is the time of the $k$th return to $x$. Let $Y_k=\sum_{t=\tau_{k-1}^+}^{\tau_k^+-1}X_t$, which is the sum of $X_t$ between the $(k-1)$th and the $k$th visit of $x$. The question is to show

> $Y_k$ where $k=1,2,...$ are i.i.d. random variables.

Anyone can help prove the above statement? Thank you!

---

**PS:** The previous version of this question and a possibly related material is posted below.

> Given a finite-length Markov chain $X_0,X_1,...,X_n$ with finite state space, define a random variable $\tau$ as stopping time if event $\{\tau = t\}$ can be determined by $X_0,X_1,...,X_t$ for any $0 \le t\le n$. The question is to show
>
> 1. $X_0,X_1,...,X_{\tau - 1}$ are independent from $X_{\tau}, X_{\tau + 1}, ..., X_{n}$.
> 2. $\sum_{t=0}^{\tau-1} X_t$ and $\sum_{t=\tau}^n X_t$ are i.i.d.
>
> [image]

Comment: Note that the property that "1. $X_0,X_1,...,X_{\tau - 1}$ are independent from $X_{\tau}, X_{\tau + 1}, ..., X_{n}$" is squarely wrong.

Comment: @JKnecht I share your puzzlement (but I would prefer that you do not appear to accuse me, which might be due to the fact that you typed the wrong name in the middle of your comment).

Comment: @Tony I reverted your question to its state when JKnecht posted their answer. Do not change the question again.

Comment: @Did I understand your concern, but I have to say I edit the question for a reason. if you guys really know what I am asking, you will find two versions are actually the same. They are all asking about: the stopping times split the Markov chains into independent parts, the sums over each parts are independent. The only actually difference is that the first version only has one stopping time, and the second version generalizes it to many stopping times. If we know how to solve the first version, then the second version should be solved as well.

Comment: @Did Also the mention of strong Markov property might be misleading, so I remove it from the question. JKnecht did reply to my question. I appreciate the answer, but I think it is far away from a real solution. I started a bounty, so I want my question more generalized and clear.

Comment: @JKnecht I answered to your concern in the comments. The two versions are **asking the same question** and I don't think there is an ethical problem here. I saw your answer and I appreciate your effort, but I have to say that is not really a solution. I edited the question because I started a bounty, and I want it expressed more clearly.

Comment: @Did I think this is an informal using of concept for discrete probabilities. The textbook says it this way, so I posted this way. Whey it says "$X_0,X_1,...,X_{\tau - 1}$ are independent from $X_{\tau}, X_{\tau + 1}, ..., X_{n}$", I believe it means the events $\{X_0=x_0,X_1=x_1,...,X_{\tau - 1}=x_{\tau-1}\}$ and $\{X_{\tau}=x_{\tau}, X_{\tau + 1}=x_{\tau+1}, ..., X_{n}=x_n\}$ are always independent no matter what those "x_{...}" are.

Comment: Once again, this is wrong, formally and informally (and certainly not the way the book states it). You might want to build counterexamples, they abound.

Comment: @Did I deleted my comment. I really did not want it to look like I was accusing you of anything. It was just to get your attention. And like the comments are now it still is obvious what occurred.

Comment: @Tony Tbh i dont remember anything about sums in your original question. I remember only that you focused on asking about the independence of $X_0...X_{\tau -1}$ and $X_{\tau}...X_n$. But it was a while since i wrote my answer tho. Nevertheless my answer maybe was not particularly good, presumably because i misunderstood your question. No hard feelings, but like Did (and I) are pointing out you should not change you question/wording of the question to that extent.

Comment: @Tony It make those who have answered look bad because ppl might wonder what they are talking about and even start downvoting the answer. Next time, just ask a new question.

Comment: @JKnecht I understand and I apologize for my editing of the original question. I understand it took a while to type in an answer and I really appreciate your effort. Another big motivation for the change is the bounty. If I start a new question I need to wait 2 days to start a bounty.I want the solution because this looks essential for me to understand Ergodic theorem for Markov chains. My study has been delayed by this for like two days. Anyway, cheers! I won't do that again.

Comment: @Tony I understand. Lets forget this now and hope someone will be able to give you a good answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have updated the answer to a full solution. The solution almost only uses elementary probability calculation without any heavy machinery. So I think it is most understandable.

**PART I**

For the "identically distributed" part, it follows from the strong Markov property stated in your material.

Let ${I_k} = \tau _{x,k}^ +  - \tau _{x,k - 1}^ + $, then for every $k=1,2,…$, we have

> ${\Bbb P}\left\{ {{I_k} = m,{Y_k} = s|\tau _{x,k - 1}^ +  < \infty } \right\} = {{\Bbb P}_{{{\bf{\delta }}_x}}}\left\{ {{X_m} = x,{X_{m - 1}} \ne x, \ldots ,{X_1} \ne x,\mathop \sum \limits_{t = 0}^{m - 1} {X_t} = s} \right\}$

for every $m∈\Bbb N^+$ and $s$. Thus

> ${\Bbb P}\left\{ {{Y_k} = s|\tau _{x,k - 1}^ +  < \infty } \right\} = \mathop \sum \limits_{m \in {{\Bbb N}^ + }} {{\Bbb P}_{{{\bf{\delta }}_x}}}\left\{ {{X_m} = x,{X_{m - 1}} \ne x, \ldots ,{X_1} \ne x,\mathop \sum \limits_{t = 0}^{m - 1} {X_t} = s} \right\}$

from which we easily see $Y_k$ is identically distributed.

**PART II**

The "strong Markov property" stated in your material, I think, is far from sufficient to prove independence. The form of strong Markov property that we need is

> ${\Bbb P}\left( {F\bigcap H{\text{|}}\tau  < \infty ,{X_\tau } = v} \right) = {\Bbb P}\left( {F{\text{|}}\tau  < \infty ,{X_\tau } = v} \right){\Bbb P}\left( {H{\text{|}}\tau  < \infty ,{X_\tau } = v} \right)$

where $\tau$ is chosen as the present time, $F$ is any future event and $H$ is any historical event. If a time $t$ is chosen as the present time, then any event determined by $X_{t+1},X_{t+2},...$ is a future event, and any event determined by $X_0,X_1,...,X_{t-1}$ is a historical event.

The meaning of the strong Markov property is clear: information that "$\tau<\infty$ and $X_{\tau}=v$" is sufficient to decouple any future event and any historical event. We don't need other information like what exactly $\tau$ is.

The proof I have is too long to be posted here. Just assume this is true. Don't hurry. We also need to extend the above strong Markov property to multiple stopping times.

First we prove a lemma that **providing additional future and historical events as condition does not break independence**. As before let $τ$ be a stopping time, and let $F$ and $H$ be any future event and historical event. In addition, let $F_0,H_0$ be another arbitrary future event and historical event, then

> ${\Bbb P}\left( {F,H{\text{|}}\tau  < \infty ,{X_\tau } = v,{F_0},{H_0}} \right) = \frac{{{\Bbb P}\left( {F,H,\tau  < \infty ,{X_\tau } = v,{F_0},{H_0}} \right)}}{{{\Bbb P}\left( {\tau  < \infty ,{X_\tau } = v,{F_0},{H_0}} \right)}} = \frac{{{\Bbb P}\left( {F,H,{F_0},{H_0}{\text{|}}\tau  < \infty ,{X_\tau } = v} \right)}}{{{\Bbb P}\left( {{F_0},{H_0}{\text{|}}\tau  < \infty ,{X_\tau } = v} \right)}} = \frac{{{\Bbb P}\left( {F,{F_0}{\text{|}}\tau  < \infty ,{X_\tau } = v} \right){\Bbb P}\left( {H,{H_0}{\text{|}}\tau  < \infty ,{X_\tau } = v} \right)}}{{{\Bbb P}\left( {{F_0}{\text{|}}\tau  < \infty ,{X_\tau } = v} \right){\Bbb P}\left( {{H_0}{\text{|}}\tau  < \infty ,{X_\tau } = v} \right)}} = {\Bbb P}\left( {F{\text{|}}\tau  < \infty ,{X_\tau } = v,{F_0}} \right){\Bbb P}\left( {H{\text{|}}\tau  < \infty ,{X_\tau } = v,{H_0}} \right)$

Similarly

> ${\Bbb P}\left( {F,H{\text{|}}\tau  < \infty ,{X_\tau } = v,{F_0}} \right) = {\Bbb P}\left( {F{\text{|}}\tau  < \infty ,{X_\tau } = v,{F_0}} \right){\Bbb P}\left( {H{\text{|}}\tau  < \infty ,{X_\tau } = v} \right)$
>
> ${\Bbb P}\left( {F,H{\text{|}}\tau  < \infty ,{X_\tau } = v,{H_0}} \right) = {\Bbb P}\left( {F{\text{|}}\tau  < \infty ,{X_\tau } = v} \right){\Bbb P}\left( {H{\text{|}}\tau  < \infty ,{X_\tau } = v,{H_0}} \right)$

It follows that

> ${\Bbb P}\left( {F{\text{|}}\tau  < \infty ,{X_\tau } = v,{F_0},{H_0}} \right) = \frac{{{\Bbb P}\left( {F,\tau  < \infty ,{X_\tau } = v,{F_0},{H_0}} \right)}}{{{\Bbb P}\left( {\tau  < \infty ,{X_\tau } = v,{F_0},{H_0}} \right)}} = \frac{{{\Bbb P}\left( {F,{H_0}{\text{|}}\tau  < \infty ,{X_\tau } = v,{F_0}} \right)}}{{{\Bbb P}\left( {{H_0}{\text{|}}\tau  < \infty ,{X_\tau } = v,{F_0}} \right)}} = \frac{{{\Bbb P}\left( {F{\text{|}}\tau  < \infty ,{X_\tau } = v,{F_0}} \right){\Bbb P}\left( {{H_0}{\text{|}}\tau  < \infty ,{X_\tau } = v} \right)}}{{{\Bbb P}\left( {{H_0}{\text{|}}\tau  < \infty ,{X_\tau } = v} \right)}} = {\Bbb P}\left( {F{\text{|}}\tau  < \infty ,{X_\tau } = v,{F_0}} \right)$

meaning that providing additional future event $F_0$ in the condition does not break the independence between any future event and historical event. Similarly we can calculate

> ${\Bbb P}\left( {H{\text{|}}\tau  < \infty ,{X_\tau } = v,{F_0},{H_0}} \right)={\Bbb P}\left( {H{\text{|}}\tau  < \infty ,{X_\tau } = v,{H_0}} \right)$

It further follows that

> ${\Bbb P}\left( {F,H{\text{|}}\tau  < \infty ,{X_\tau } = v,{F_0},{H_0}} \right) = {\Bbb P}\left( {F{\text{|}}\tau  < \infty ,{X_\tau } = v,{F_0}} \right){\Bbb P}\left( {H{\text{|}}\tau  < \infty ,{X_\tau } = v,{H_0}} \right) = {\Bbb P}\left( {F{\text{|}}\tau  < \infty ,{X_\tau } = v,{F_0},{H_0}} \right){\Bbb P}\left( {H{\text{|}}\tau  < \infty ,{X_\tau } = v,{F_0},{H_0}} \right)$

by which we conclude that providing any additional future event $F_0$ and historical event $H_0$ does not break the independence between any future event and historical event. From another perspective, if the conditions can be broken into $τ<∞,X_τ=v$, a future event $F_0$ and a historical event $H_0$, then any future event $F$ and historical event $H$ are independent.

Now given ${\tau _0} = 0$ and multiple stopping times ${\tau _1} <  \ldots  < {\tau _k}$ , let $_$ be an event determined by ${X_{{\tau _{j - 1}}}},{X_{{\tau _{j - 1}} + 1}}, \ldots ,{X_{{\tau _j} - 1}}$ for $j = 1,2, \ldots ,k$, , let $_{+1}$ be an event determined by ${X_{{\tau _k}}},{X_{{\tau _k} + 1}}, \ldots $. In addition, let $K = \left\{ {{X_{{\tau _1}}} = {v_1}, \ldots ,{X_{{\tau _k}}} = {v_k}} \right\}$. We will prove the following **strong Markov property for multiple stopping times**.

> ${\Bbb P}\left( {\mathop \bigcap \limits_{j = 1}^k {H_j}|{\tau _k} < \infty ,K} \right) = \mathop \prod \limits_{j = 1}^k {\Bbb P}\left( {{H_j}|{\tau _k} < \infty ,K} \right)$

First choose $τ_k$ as the present time, then $\mathop \bigcap \limits_{j = 1}^k {H_j}$ an historical event, and ${H_{k + 1}}$ is a future event. Also note event

> $\left\{ {{\tau _k} < \infty } \right\}\bigcap K = \left\{ {{\tau _k} < \infty ,{X_{{\tau _k}}} = {v_k}} \right\}\bigcap \left\{ {{X_{{\tau _1}}} = {v_1}, \ldots ,{X_{{\tau _{k - 1}}}} = {v_{k - 1}}} \right\}$

where $\left\{ {{X_{{\tau _1}}} = {v_1}, \ldots ,{X_{{\tau _{k - 1}}}} = {v_{k - 1}}} \right\}$ is a historical event, then

> ${\Bbb P}\left( {\mathop \bigcap \limits_{j = 1}^{k + 1} {H_j}|{\tau _k} < \infty ,K} \right) = {\Bbb P}\left( {{H_{k + 1}}|{\tau _k} < \infty ,K} \right){\Bbb P}\left( {\mathop \bigcap \limits_{j = 1}^k {H_j}|{\tau _k} < \infty ,K} \right)$

Likewise, to solve ${\Bbb P}\left( {\mathop \bigcap \limits_{j = 1}^k {H_j}|{\tau _k} < \infty ,K} \right)$, choose $τ_{k-1}$ as the present time, and it is easy to verify that $\{τ_k<∞\}⋂K$ can be broken into $τ_{k-1}<∞,X_{τ_{k-1} }=v$, a future event and a historical event. Thus

> ${\Bbb P}\left( {\mathop \bigcap \limits_{j = 1}^k {H_j}|{\tau _k} < \infty ,K} \right) = {\Bbb P}\left( {{H_k}|{\tau _k} < \infty ,K} \right){\Bbb P}\left( {\mathop \bigcap \limits_{j = 1}^{k - 1} {H_j}|{\tau _k} < \infty ,K} \right)$

Iteratively, we arrive at ${\Bbb P}\left( {\mathop \bigcap \limits_{j = 1}^{k+1} {H_j}|{\tau _k} < \infty ,K} \right) = \mathop \prod \limits_{j = 1}^{k+1} {\Bbb P}\left( {{H_j}|{\tau _k} < \infty ,K} \right)$.

Now the "independent" part of your problem is a piece of cake. The $k$th return times are nothing more than the stopping times $\tau_k$ discussed above, and finite state space and irreducibility guarantees they are finite. Events $\{Y_k=s_k\},k=1,2,...$ are nothing more than events determined by ${X_{{\tau _{k - 1}}}},{X_{{\tau _{k - 1}} + 1}}, \ldots ,{X_{{\tau _k} - 1}}$. Thus events $\{Y_k=s_k\},k=1,2,...$ are independent for any $s_k,k=1,2,...$. $Y_k,k=1,2,...$ are discrete RVs, then $Y_k,k=1,2,...$ are independent.